# Change CSS color of specific data in a table

Tags: python, html, css

I want to change the specific color of values in my HTML data table but I don't know how to do it. I would like to change the data's color of my Table's cell.

For example,

```
if (cell.value >= 10){

   cell.color = red
}
```

I have a Dataframe that I send back to fill a table like this in my file (.html).

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Table SUA</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<div class=page>

  <h1>Table of fixed bugs according to version for OS{{titre}}</h1>
  {% for table in tables %}
    <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.bram.us/2016/10/13/css-attribute-value-less-than-greater-than-equals-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `class` attribute to 'target' the data (the `class` can be in a `div` or `span` or `td` that contains the data). I would look at the data before you send it to the table and set, for instance, `class="tenPlus"` for every piece of data that is `>= 10` You can store this data in a separate list or in a dictionary and loop through it as you send the data to the table. Then you can easily use Javascript to change the color of the element. Here is a very simple example:

```js
var tenPlus, nineDown;

tenPlus = document.getElementsByClassName('tenPlus');
nineDown = document.getElementsByClassName('nineDown');

for (var i = 0; i < tenPlus.length; i++) {
  tenPlus[i].style.background = "red";
}

for (var i = 0; i < nineDown.length; i++) {
  nineDown[i].style.background = "blue";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tenPlus">12</td>
    <td class="nineDown">7</td>
    <td class="tenPlus">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tenPlus">22</td>
    <td class="tenPlus">33</td>
    <td class="nineDown">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nineDown">2</td>
    <td class="nineDown">8</td>
    <td class="nineDown">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```